# Python not found in the Open WRT MenuConfig --> Languages

Tags: python, openwrt

I am trying to include python in openwrt. It's not showing up in the open wrt menuconfig. I can see only Lua and nothing else under language options. While checking it shows me python ... OK , perl ... OK. Am I missing any steps?

Comment: Would you say this is a programming-related question? Perhaps you could ask on SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cd (to/openwrt/path)
$ scripts/feeds update
$ scripts/feeds install python
$ make menuconfig
```

Comment: thanks for your help that's what I was looking for. Information is quiet "enough" to me

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need search available python version:

```
./scripts/feeds search python
./scripts/feeds install micropython
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install your feed, not just update them.

```
./scripts/feeds install -a
```

^^^ This worked for me, but it will take a while to complete. It adds all the available packages to the menuconfig -- it may do more than that as well.

or specify your specific package(s):

```
./scripts/feeds install [packages, ...]
```

or specify an entire feed:

```
./scripts/feeds install -p -a myfeed
```